# I edited a tag and it got approved, but is displaying incorrectly

Tags: bug, tags, tag-excerpt

I [edited a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/maven/info) and my change was approved, but, unfortunately, it's not displaying properly. The change consisted in adding a `[tag:gradle]` (which I thought would display the tag; however, this turned out to not work). There is no way to flag it, or revert, as far as I can see. Is this a bug, or limitation, or is it on purpose? Further down in the tag's description, you can see that other tags are listed and that works fine.

Comment: it also displays properly in the revision history

Comment: Perhaps this needs to be improved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage guidance (aka wiki excerpts) can never show anything but plain text. Unfortunately, this isn't called out all that clearly, and the revision history is misleading, since it's designed for the other site posts that *do* allow Markdown.

The only thing to do is edit again, removing the failed markup.